# Varying Vagrants WordPress box - restart Apache

Tags: wordpress, vagrant

I've got a Varying Vagrants Vagrant box with WordPress installed.

I've just ssh'd in but can't find out how to restart Apache.

Here's what I've tried (along with the errors):

```
$ sudo restart apache2
restart: Unknown job: apache2

$ sudo service apache2 restart
apache2: unrecognized service

apachectl restart
The program 'apachectl' is currently not installed. To run 'apachectl' please ask your administrator to install the package 'apache2'
```

If it helps, `uname` gives:

```
$ uname -a
Linux vvv 3.13.0-92-generic #139-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 28 20:42:26 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: how did you install apache at first place ? if nothing works, kill the process and start from apache command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Varying Vagrant Vagrants](https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV) does not use apache as web server. In the readme file Apache is not listed as installed. Instead of apache it uses nginx as web server.

In [provision script](https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV/blob/develop/provision/provision.sh#L52-L53) you would find these two lines:

```
# nginx is installed as the default web server
nginx
```

That's why you can't find apache. If you want to restart nginx then you can try:

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

Comment: Aah, that would explain it. When you've got many Vagrant boxes with different configurations it gets confusing - leaky abstractions and all that.